# Android Studio Gradle For New Projects

Tags: android, android-studio

I've been using eclipse for all of my developing but decided to transition over to Android Studio. Having a bit of an issue with Gradle.

As noted a few times before, every time a new project is initiated AS will try to re-download gradle 2.2.1. This takes quite some time and I'm looking to avoid it.

Per some peoples suggestions, I went to gradle.org and downloaded version 2.2.1, saved it to a folder, and attempted to point to this directory. This seemed to not work.

I did: **File-->Settings-->Gradle** 
then changed the Service Directory Path to numerous folders that are found within the gradle download. None seemed to work.

I tried the main gradle 2.2.1 all folder, and quite a few identically named folders found within the "wrapper" folders. This folder has quite a long path to it.

What am I doing wrong here???? I feel as if simple set-up shouldn't be this problematic. I'm hoping this isn't a bit of foreshadowing for what's to come when I try to use this program... hahaha....

Comment: Gradle doesn't redownload anything that is already cached so I'm not sure what you are trying to avoid.

Comment: Every time I start a new project Android Studio redownloads grade 2.2.1-all